# postgreSQL about temp table: cannot open relation OID 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a query on PostgreSql 9.5.8 to save a query's result to a temp table and then select some rows into another table.

```
select * into temporary mytemp1 from tbl1;
insert into tbl2 (id,val) 
with sub as (select id, val from  mytemp1 order by id desc, val limit 5) select 
* from sub;
```

i got error:

```
ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 0
SQL state: XX000
```

It seems that mytemp1 is not found ?

thanks for any help !

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: If I run your queries in `psql`, I don't get this error. Please describe your setup in more detail.